# Using floats within a grid at variable heights

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, grid

I have the following grid and each red block is a `div`. As you can see, the longest `div` is pushing the bottom two `divs`lower, creating unwanted space.

[image]

Here is how I would like to have it, so the space is tighter and not broken by the longest `div`:

[image]

Is there a CSS solution to this, or an alternative to Masonry / Isotope?

Comment: do all your blocks have known height?

Comment: Nope, variable heights. Will change dependent on the CMS used.

Comment: give me minute I'll give it a try

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to accomplish what you want using floats. You can however use:

```
div{
position:absolute;
}
```

This will achieve what you want because it will allow you to position each box exactly where you want, down to the pixel. Be aware that this will remove each div from the document flow. For that reason and a few others, I recommend constraining the divs within some sort of container that is set to:

```
position: relative;
```

This will limit the scope of the absolute positioning.